# How to type constrain generics scenario

Tags: c#, generics, types, constraints

I am trying to make a custom `Collection<X, Y...> : ICollection<X>, IList<Y>` of sorts. It inherits from [`ICollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/92t2ye13%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), and [`IList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/5y536ey6%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) because I decided to go with the generic versions as they are more modern.
Here are the constraints I need:

- items of type `T` (value types or reference types) can be added to the collection.
- Items of type `IEnumerable<T>` or `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` so forth and so on infinitely down the line can also be added :)

How can you make a Generic class with these constraints, i.e. what would the where clause be?
Is this even possible? Would this be an appropriate place to use the non-generic `ICollection`, `IList` and no generics?

Comment: I don't think you can... Assuming the goal is to make `ICollection<?>.Add` accept all types you've mentioned.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought, I guess in this scenario it would be acceptable to utilize the Boxing/Unboxing scenario adding/removing objects.

Comment: Do you really need both `X` and `Y` types in the same collection?

Answer (score -1):

As described on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) type constrain is possible and you can accept one or multiple constraints.

Also check [WHERE usage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you want?

```
public interface IBlock<T> 
    where T : IBlock<T>
{
}

public class Block<T> : Collection<T>, IBlock<Block<T>>
{        
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list_1=new Block<int[]>();
        list_1.Add(new int[] { 1, 2, 3} );
        list_1.Add(new int[] { 4, 5} );
        var list_2=new Block<int[]>();
        list_2.Add(new int[] { -1, 4} );
        list_2.Add(new int[] { 2, 6, 8} );
        var list_list =new Block<Block<int[]>>();
        list_list.Add(list_1);
        list_list.Add(list_2);

        int x=list_list[1][0][1];
        // x=4
    }
}
```

Comment: That is a good question. Also downvoting without a proper explanations won't help much